# Stack trace and exceptions in console

Tags: node.js, error-handling, express

How can I get the same **stack trace** and **exceptions** as I get with

```
app.use(express.errorHandler({
    showStack: true, 
    dumpExceptions: true
}));
```

but only in console?

`console.trace(err)` doesn't give the same result as I get from the above.

Comment: What is different in console?

Answer (score 0):

`console.trace()` prints the stack trace where it was hit, not the trace of an error you pass it. You can see the stack trace of the error using simple `console.log(err)`, it will output both the exception and the stack trace. If you need to see only the stack trace, you can `console.log(err.stack)`